# jQuery live("click", function() {...}) doesn't work for body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this simple code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cupidvogel/CRYDV/). It doesn't work for either the actual `click` event or the one which is commented out. Can anybody explain why? I have had issues with `not` previously also...

Comment: Please always include here the relevant code.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()`  in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: @dystroy, Well, everybody tells the OP to provide a fiddle, that's why I did that..

Comment: @Cupidvogel It's mandatory to include the relevant code in the question and it's a good practice to also provide a fiddle so that people can test it.

Comment: Okay, will do that from now on..:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7, and has been removed in v1.9.

You should replace it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`.on` has 2 syntaxes for binding elements, whereas `.live` only had 1.

If the element exists at the time you are binding, you do it like this:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(){
});
```

You can even use the shorthand:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
});
```

If the element does not exist at the time, or new ones will be added (which is what `.live` was normally used for), you need to use "event delegation":

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){
});
```

NOTE: You want to bind to the closest static element, not always `document`.

Answer (score 7):

That's simply because the `live` function, which was long deprecated, has now been removed from jQuery.

Replace

```
$("body").live("click",function() { alert("coo"); });
```

with

```
$("body").on("click",function() { alert("coo"); });
```

Look at the top right of [this page](http://api.jquery.com/live/) : "removed 1.9".

Comment: Is that the only reason? I knew `live` is deprecated, but doesn't it work at all?

Comment: It's not just deprecated.  It's been removed in v2 which you targeted with your jsFiddle example.  Roll it back to 1.8 and it works.

Comment: It's been removed since 1.9

Comment: Oh, I did not know that it has been removed. Does `on` provide any performance benefits compared to `live`?

Comment: The page I link to explains why on is better than live. And generally yes, you get performances gains by using on instead of live.

Comment: The fact that .on works and .live doesn't work should be more than enough of a performance benefit to warrant going to it imo.

Answer (score 2):

The `live()` method has been deprecated and deleted.  Use `on()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jquery 2.0` version then you have to get the `migrate 1.0` too

see this: http://jsfiddle.net/CRYDV/1/

otherwise you have to work with `.on()` handler as suggested in above answers.